# React.js use ThemeProvider based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hi all as per title I would like based on the route to use a different theme provider my code looks like that:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
 ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme="MyThemes.default">
      <CssBaseline />
       <App />
```

,
rootElement,
);

where

```
const myThemes= {
 default: createMuiTheme({ ...defaultTheme, ...typography, overrides: { ...muiCssBaseline, 
  ...muiTableOverrides } }),
 myother_theme: createMuiTheme({ ...myOtherTheme, ...typography, overrides: { 
 ...muiCssBaseline, ...muiTableOverrides } }),
```

};

so when i am in a particular route I want to use myother_theme

I was making a wrapper component to call in the index.js like that

```
const ThemeProviderChange = ({ children }) => {
 const [theme, setTheme] = useState(Themes.default);
 const isMyLocation= window.location.pathname === "/MYlOCATION/PATH"?? true;
 
 const url = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMyLocation) {
     setTheme(MyThemes.myother_theme);
 
    } else {
     setTheme(MyThemes.default);
    }

   }, [url]);
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
   };

  export default ThemeProviderChange;
```

but to be working it requires the user to make a manual refresh.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array dependence in useEffect hook not dispatch using window. For this you should use useLocation of react-router-dom.

I make this example https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-theme-provider-mui-based-in-routes-tt1d4 to resolve this problem.

```
const location = useLocation();
  const isMyLocation = location.pathname === "/MYlOCATION/PATH";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMyLocation) {
      setTheme(MyThemes.myother_theme);
    } else {
      setTheme(MyThemes.default);
    }
  }, [location.pathname, isMyLocation]);
```

Futhermore you need add BrowserRouter wrapper context in app for listening changes in state routes.

Comment: It looks very good. I fell we are close to the solution,however I am facing some small issues for the uselocation (see update).In each case I upvote your question it can be useful to others!

Comment: I played around another bit with my wrapping and now it works. Thank you a lot for your time !